# Cascading animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to give the same animation to a set of elements, but each incrementally delayed so that the animations make a sort of a 'wave'.

I made a fiddle about it; http://jsfiddle.net/ttLJ3/

Basically each element be delayed by increments of 50ms, do a thing, wait 300ms and undo it.

It just simply doesn't seem to work. It does nothing. If I remove the `.delay(300).show()`, all elements disappear immediately.

How can I make this work? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix your problem here.

http://jsfiddle.net/ttLJ3/1/

Since `delay` works with the `fx queue`, you have to pass in an integer of sorts for delay to work otherwise the hide and show methods will execute immediately. Making it seem as if nothing is happening at all. I passed in `0` to each of the hide and show calls to fix the issue.

```
$(this).delay(50 * index).hide(0).delay(300).show(0);
```

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly stupid :) Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Lame I had the first response. Give me the answer! ;)  Well hide and show are quite useful for hiding an element not in the `fx queue`, so instead of writing `display:none` in css you can do $(el).hide();

Comment: I actually originally wanted to use a plugin method instead of `hide()` and `show()`... now that I know what's the issue, how do I turn those into 'animation methods'?

Comment: First by exactly the number of seconds it took me to add the link to the doco and quote the relevant bit...

Comment: `http://api.jquery.com/animate/` Using (some) css properties, you can animate an element.

Comment: I actually do need to use the specific plugin method -- showing and hiding a tooltip replacement. Is there some hack so I could like... I dunno, `.animate(0)` a function call with one parameter?

Comment: @EmphramStavanger - are you saying you want one of your own functions to work within the animation queue? If so there are ways to make that work, but I suggest you post it as a new question and show the function code.

Comment: I ended up making a very very sad hack: `.animate({'display':'block},0,function(){ $(this).theFunc(theVar); })`... no, no I'm not proud.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`.hide()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), "When a duration is provided, `.hide()` becomes an animation method." Apparently this means that if you don't provide a duration the hiding isn't done in the animation queue and so doesn't work with `.delay()`.

So try adding a short duration to `.hide()` and `.show()`:

```
$(this).delay(50 * index).hide(1).delay(300).show(1);
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ttLJ3/2/